# Wordpress plugin id not found

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have a problem I can not get the id from my sql table to delete a line.

If someone could help me please.

```
    <?php

include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'\connection.php';
global $wpdb;
$adherent_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'fc_adherents';
$adherent_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM fc_adherents ORDER BY id_adherent ASC ");

foreach ($adherent_data as $data) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="row" class="check-column"><label class="screen-reader-text" for="cb-select-268">Sélectionner $data->prenom </label>
<input id="cb-select-268" type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="268">
<div class="locked-indicator">
<span class="locked-indicator-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="screen-reader-text">“f” est verrouillé</span>
</div></th>';
    $id=$table_ligne['id_adherents'];
    echo '<td/>';
    echo $data->nom;
    echo "</br><a href='http://lab-origami.local/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gestion+adherents%2Finclus%2Fmodif.php'id='$id&o=u'>Modifier</a></br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='supprimer' value='supprimer '>";
    echo '<td/>';
    echo $data->prenom;
    echo '<td/>';
    echo $data->courriel;
    echo '<td/>';
    echo $data->telephone;
    echo '<td/>';
    echo $data->date_adhesion;
    echo '<td/>';
    echo $data->types_abonnement;
    echo '<td/>';
    echo $data->types_d_adherents;
    echo '<td/>';
    echo $data->type_tarif;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $data->id_adherent;
    echo '<tr/>';
}
?>
</table>
<h3 align="right"><?php echo count($adherent_data)?> éléments</h3>
<?php
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'adherents';
if(isset($_POST["supprimer"])){
global $wpdb;
     $wpdb->delete( $table_name, [ 'id_adherent' => $data->id_adherent] );
    }
?>
```

as you may have noticed the problem comes from the id that gets deleted with each return of the foreach

Comment: Table prefix is not correct in delete

Answer (score 0):

You are using table name `fc_adherents` in select query but you are using `adherents` in delete.

you need to change the table name or prefix .

**your select query table**

```
global $wpdb;
$adherent_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'fc_adherents';
```

**your Delete query table**

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'adherents';
```

Comment: I modify it as you told me but no change ... thank you for sending me a word to try to correct my problem

Comment: just now I have tried this and it has to walk but the problem '' id_adherents = '' I do not know what to put after so that its this selects automatically without that I give it the id
$adherent_data = $wpdb->get_results("DELETE FROM fc_adherents WHERE id_adherent = ")